# What is the use of a state management library in a SSR app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im using NextJS as library to serve a SSR application. In the documentation and examples I read a lot about using a state management library for this. I am used to using a state management library on a client-side rendered application, but I dont really see the added value in a SSR application. On the client I would use this to store settings like profile, UI-state and maybe some results from API-calls. Whenever I navigate, this store stays intact.  However, in a SSR application when a navigation occurs, a new request comes in, where all the JavaScript gets loaded again, right? Which means my store will get build from zero again.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you my thoughts from my little experience during this year using Next (SPA, SSR and SSG).

There's no one rule for all I think but it depends from different factors. I'll try to recap them from my experience:

## SSR

1. Your content change every minute/hour/day and it is mandatory for you to have it online asap (SEO reasons maybe)
2. you can't run `yarn build` every change of content or it is too hard/long to develop/manage an automatic system (`CI/CD`) that deploy on your behalf;
3. Is ok for you to manage a server (or lambdas) and you're aware of costs and scalability potential issues (e.g. high peak traffic in some hours);
4. You need for some other reasons the power of a server: e.g. need to change the content based on user device/location/useragent.

---

## SSG

1. You're the one who makes changes to your application (or at least the one who approves them) so you can afford to run `yarn build` every time something change;
2. You don't want to manage a server and work only with, to keep things simple, static storage services (s3, blob storage, etc) and on top a CDN for boost your application download;
3. You can afford to create an automatic system (CI/CD) where every change (insert, update, commit, whatever) it runs your deploy commands;
4. Is ok for you, time speaking, to generate (worst case possible) all the pages and upload them again due to some big change;

---

Of course here I'm not mentioning all the `e2e` tests flows cause it may change from situation to situation as well as the dynamic parts like javascript that may compose your application and could be not part of the static generated content( ad, analytics, login etc) or CSS.

I think there are more other reasons I'm not seeing right now, but hope at least to give you some ideas/feedbacks for your choice.

Cheers